# Maximum number of processes in Windows XP, Vista and 7

Tags: windows, process

How many processes can Windows support at the same time? This question is nothing to do with parellel processing of any sort. Processes can be running, waiting in the queue, sleeping etc,

Comment: The process ID is a 32-bit unsigned integer. Other things may limit further.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a limit, If you have enough hardware and good software there is no limit. But you will run into a lot of problems along the way. You should check and post your research because there is not much information on this topic.

Edit. You should check out this question [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/694421/is-there-a-maximum-anything-when-running-a-high-number-of-processes-on-windows)
So there is a limit but its really high Like the 32 bit integer limit

Comment: I'm 99% sure you're wrong. The limit may be practically unreachable, but it's probably there. For one, processes have IDs which are stored in a finite amount of a memory, so system can run out of them.

Comment: Yes the 32 bit integer limit but its not possible on windows

Comment: What's not possible?